# Different output format in R

Tags: r

I am trying to solve the HackerRank challenge with R. My program can get the same number as the reference output, but the format seems different.

```
plusMinus <- function(arr) {
  pos <- neg <- zero <- 0
  for (i in 1:length(arr)) {
    if (arr[i] == 0) {
      zero <- zero + 1
    }
    else if (arr[i] > 0) {
      pos <- pos + 1
    } else {
      neg <- neg + 1
    }
  }
  print(format(pos/length(arr), digits=6, nsmall=6))
  print(format(neg/length(arr), digits=6, nsmall=6))
  print(format(zero/length(arr), digits=6, nsmall=6))
}
```

My results are in string format, while the reference result is in numeric format; my results start each line with [1], while the reference results start with nothing. I am not sure how to align my results to the reference.

My Result

```
> plusMinus(arr)
[1] "0.500000"
[1] "0.333333"
[1] "0.166667"
```

Reference Result

```
> plusMinus(arr)
0.500000
0.333333
0.166667
```

Comment: `format` will return a character value: `format(1.125, digits = 2)` returns `"1.1"`.

Comment: Yeah. You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```r
cat(format(c(
     mean(arr>0),
     mean(arr<0),
     mean(arr==0))), sep = "\n")
```

will print just the numbers.  If you really want the numbers printed and *no* output from the function, you should probably return `invisible(NULL)` from the function ...

Comment: It works. Thanks for your clever and elegant codes.